# Item builder in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a little advice here.  I'm relatively new to react and have a little project I want to build simply for practice.  Essentially what I'm trying to do is create an app that will list all the items in my freezer and refrigerator.  The idea is that the user will be able to use a form to upload the item name, description, date purchased, if it goes in freezer or fridge, and an image.  Once the form is filled out it will add that item to the appropriate section.

I have a database set up on Firebase and have reactstrap for the ui stuff.  Im not quite sure how to sew it all together.  Anyone who can point me in the right direction or point me to similar projects would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, this question is too broad. You should start building your website and ask for help when you are in trouble

Comment: Your question is too general. You need to start doing it, show your code and specify what is wrong or working unexpectedly.

Comment: My apologies. The only thing im really in need of advice on is the posting data to Firebase and retrieving it.  I'm assuming this can be done with axios.

Comment: @user1568811 yes, you can use axios for that, or even jQuerry AJAX, but considering you're building a small personal project, you can avoid additional dependencies by using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) that's native in most new browsers and has a relatively simple interface